# Django - Advanced query depending of the relationships of a model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length= 100, blank=True, null=True)

class OrderState(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length= 100, blank=True, null=True)

class OrderDetail(models.Model):
  order = models.ForeignKey( Order )
  state = models.ForeignKey( OrderState )
```

We will assume that two kinds of states exists: 'in process' and 'finished'.

So, the idea is to make a query on OrderDetail model that return details which state is 'in process' for orders that doesn't have any detail with state 'Finished'. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
OrderDetail.objects.filter(state__name="in process").exclude(order__name="Finished")
```